# login sqlplus and execute sql file in dockerfile

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus

I want to wrtite DockerFile (from [oracle-xe-11g](https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-xe-11g/)) with copying and runing sql script.

How to correctly write a command to login sqlplus and execute sql file

written docker file

```
FROM sath89/oracle-xe-11g
USER root
RUN mkdir - p /home/test
RUN chown -R oracle:root /home/test
USER oracle
COPY ora.schema.sql /home/test
RUN ???????
```

written SQL script

```
CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test1;
GRANT CREATE ANY SEQUENCE     TO test;
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be adding your sql file to the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ folder in the Dockerfile like this:

```
ADD host/path/to/your/sql/your_sql_file.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

You don't really need anything else for this to work, the sql file will be automatically executed.